# Add an application to the Open With Menu

Tags: menu

I'm using a Samsung Note II running Jelly Bean 4.1.2.

I would like to add an application to the open with list. I have downloaded a photo editing app. While in the gallery, I would like to be able to select a picture and open it with this app but it's not in the list.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well this is defined per app in its `manifest`. It registers to a certain `Intent`.
The app that implemented the 'open with' option checks which applications react to a certain `Intent`, and shows the list of those applications.

I don't think you can modify this at runtime.

(Or you could create a new application which reacts the the 'open with' and creates another Intent which the photo editing app reacts to.)